# SQL Server: how to create a table from a pivot table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table like this,

[image]

and I have pivoted it to the following with the code,

```
select * 
from 
(
  select  *
  from table1
) a
pivot 
(
avg(col3)
 for col2 in ([a],[b],[c],[d])
) as pv;
```

[image]

How can I create a new table from the pivot table pv? I have tried select * into newTable, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: try dynamic sql

Comment: Although the simple and correct answer is to use "into newTable" as you tried originally, you have to have permission to do that + once the table is there, you need to think of what you would do next time. Drop and recreate? Truncate and insert? Or just keep it as a static table? Those all depend on your needs and likely you would want to have a temp table instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create it on the fly with `INTO`

```
SELECT * INTO #TAB
FROM 
(
  SELECT  *
  FROM TABLE1
) A
PIVOT 
(
AVG(COL3)
 FOR COL2 IN ([A],[B],[C],[D])
) AS PV;
```

With Schema provided by Chanukya. **(Worked for me)**

```
CREATE TABLE #D
(
COL1 INT,
COL2 VARCHAR(10),
COL3 INT
)
INSERT INTO #D VALUES
(1,'A',11),
(2,'B',22),
(3,'C',33),
(4,'D',44)

SELECT * INTO #PIVOT_RESULT
FROM (
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM #D
)AS A
PIVOT 
(
AVG(COL3)
FOR COL2 IN ([A],[B],[C],[D])
) AS PV;


SELECT * FROM #PIVOT_RESULT
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

Make sure the columns in your select is equal to the columns in the new table.

```
INSERT INTO NewTable
select * 
from 
(
  select  *
  from table1
) a
pivot 
(
avg(col3)
 for col2 in ([a],[b],[c],[d])
) as pv;
```

If you don't want an actual table, you want this data to be accessed throughout your query then you can make use of a temporary table `#TempTbl` and then access data from `#TempTbl`.

```
INSERT INTO #TempTbl
select * 
from 
(
  select  *
  from table1
              ) a
 pivot 
 (
   avg(col3)
   for col2 in ([a],[b],[c],[d])
                                  ) as pv;
```

Comment: does that mean I have to create a new table first before I do this? @Jibin Balachandran

Comment: @Wilheim yes, you will have to create a table with same number of columns and datatype. If you just want to access the result set throughout the query, you can make use of temp table. Like `INSERT INTO #TempTbl` and can query on `TempTbl`.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way to do that is to use "into" clause as you guessed originally. Since you didn't share your code, we don't know what you might have done wrong. Just add "into tableName" to your own pivoting code:

```
select * into myPivotedTable 
from 
(
  select  *
  from table1
) a
pivot 
(
avg(col3)
 for col2 in ([a],[b],[c],[d])
) as pv;
```

PS: I assume you have permission to create a table.